On Generating Barcodes with Pst-Barcode
This is a follow-up question to the one posed in Generating ISBN Barcodes.
Prior to posting the MWE code:
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{9780895558213}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{ean13}%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}

with the output

I had intended to enter a fictitious ISBN; something perhaps, like 9780123456789. However, the code (to be compiled with xelatex) would not execute. In fact, it only seemed to work when I entered a valid ISBN.
QUESTION: Does the pst-barcode package only work for real ISBNs; and if so, for how recent an ISBN? If I obtain, say, an ISBN today (even though the book may not be published for another month or so), will I be able to generate a barcode for it using the pst-barcode package? If not, how might I generate a barcode for a valid ISBN for a yet-to-be-self-published book?
Thank you.

The ISBN is checked for validity, not for “existence”. The last digit is a check digit, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39725/4427

@egreg Thank you for this link. When I made up the MWE, I tried changing just the last digit of the ISBN to something else and the code did not work,. Hence, the above question. Thanks again.

EDIT
Apparently, \psbarcode is able to supply the check digit by itself if a 12 digit number is given.
Thanks to Terry Burton for pointing this out.
I'll leave the code because it might be useful in other situations.

The command \psbarcode checks whether the ISBN code is valid, that is, the sequence of 13 digits has the correct check digit.
You can generate the check digit given a 12 digit number and pass it to \psbarcode. In the examples below, the second ISBN is completely fictitious, but there's no complaint. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN for the algorithm.
Given a 12-digit number, \fixISBN will (expandably) produce the ISBN number by supplying the final check digit.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fixISBN}{m}
 {
  #1
  \__egreg_fixisbn:e
  {
   \int_mod:nn
    {
     ( \__egreg_fixisbn_full:n { #1 } )% sum all digits
     +
     2*( \__egreg_fixisbn_even:n { #1 } )% sum twice the odd position digits
    }
    {10}
  }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_fixisbn:n 
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 0 } { 0 } { \int_eval:n { 10 - #1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__egreg_fixisbn:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_fixisbn_full:n
 {
  0 \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__egreg_fixisbn_add:n
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_fixisbn_add:n { + #1 }

\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_fixisbn_even:n
 {
  0 \__egreg_fixisbn_even:w #1 \q_nil \q_stop
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__egreg_fixisbn_even:w #1 #2
 {
  \quark_if_nil:NF #1 { +#2 \__egreg_fixisbn_even:w }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{\fixISBN{978089555821}}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{ean13}%
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip

\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{\fixISBN{123456789012}}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{ean13}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}



Many thanks for this answer.

If the check digit is omitted, then the ean13 or isbn encoder will calculate it automatically.
